# Is 判決が[下]{くだ}る a common expression?

Tags: usage

Is 判決が下る (to pass judgment) common?

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail about your question? Where have you found this expression (in what context)? Why do you need it? So that it's a bit easier to understand what kind of answer you want? Because as stated you question is a plain yes-no question. On the other hand, are you sure of your gloss?

Comment: I saw the sentence used in a dictionary as an example.

Comment: Hate to nitpick but, which did you see, 判決**を下す** or 判決**が下る**? "To pass judgment" is 判決を[下]{くだ}す whereas 判決が[下]{くだ}る would be "judgment is passed/given". (下す is transitive and 下る is intransitive.)

Comment: To literally translate _pass judgment_ you must make 判決 into object.

Comment: Thanks  for the clarification @choco
I saw it as 判決を下した。  whole sentence is listed below :
法廷は彼に有罪の判決を下した。

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is common. 判決が下る is translated as "judgment is sentenced"

And there is a similar way of saying like 判決を下す. It is translated as "pass a judgement" and another way of saying it is 判決を言い渡す.

Comment: Is there a variation of that?  Weblio suggested 判決を言い渡渡す.

Comment: 言い渡渡す is incorrect.

Comment: 「判決を言い渡す」 is definitely  NOT another way of saying 「判決が下る」.   Please consider the transitivity.

Comment: Yes, 判決を下す is the one.